# php sending mass email through pearl mail - viewing sent messages/messages in queue

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer, mailman, mail-queue

I have a mass email setup in php using the mail.php function.

I have read the post "Sending Mass email using PHP" which was helpful, but didn't wanted to open conversation on a new post. I would like the ability to view messages in queue or past sent messages from my front end php mass email page.

Concerns:

- ability to view sent messages
- ability to cancel message sending in queue

Which is the best system for this?

- Swift Mailer
- Pear mail_queue
- Mailman

Would appreciate some advice

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a regular expression to validate an email addresses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-addresses)

Comment: I read that post, also very useful, but how about viewing a queue or saving sent emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with your code, not the concept.
Your code should validate the email before attempting to send the email, skip it if it's invalid and then continue in the loop, meaning your mass mail wont freeze on an invalid email.